# CollectionViewCell does not work properly when matching data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a problem using uicollectionview.
When I make a collectionviewcell and make a uilabel in collectionviewcell, suddenly uilabel disappeared.

First, my storyboard is like :
[image: storyBoardImage]

and, my source is like this :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = folderCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FolderCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FolderCollectionViewCell

    cell.folderLabel.frame.size.width = cellSize
    cell.folderLabel.frame.size.height = 20
    cell.folderImage.frame.size.width = cellSize
    cell.folderImage.frame.size.width = cellSize

    cell.folderLabel.text = ""
    cell.folderLabel.textColor = UIColor.flatWhite

    if(nameList[indexPath.row] == "")
    {
        cell.folderLabel.text = ""
        cell.folderLabel.frame.size = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        cell.folderImage.frame.size = CGSize(width: cellSize, height: cellSize + 20)
    }

    cell.folderImage.image = imgList[indexPath.row]
    cell.folderLabel!.text = nameList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if(nameList[indexPath.row] != "")
    {
        if(nameList[indexPath.row] != "⤴︎")
        {
            currentAlbum = nameList[indexPath.row]
        }
        var selectedAlbum = ""
        selectedAlbum = nameList[indexPath.row]
        setImageInformation(albumName: selectedAlbum)
        folderCollectionView.reloadData()
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({UIView.animate(views: self.folderCollectionView.orderedVisibleCells, animations: animations, completion: nil)} , completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let imageData = imgList[indexPath.row].jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        goToImageViewer(data : imageData!)
    }
}
```

When I launch my app, at first time the app worked properly.

[image]

But when I go into the folder and return again, the folder label disappeared.

[image]

When I debug, the data is good like this :

## print("ASJ DATA : (nameList[indexPath.row]) + (indexPath.row) + (cell.folderLabel.text) + (cell.folderLabel.frame.size.height) + (cell.folderImage.frame.size.height)")

ASJ DATA : dfgdfgd + 0 + Optional("") + 20.0 + 105.0

## cell.folderLabel.text : Optional("dfgdfgd")

ASJ DATA : dgd + 1 + Optional("") + 20.0 + 105.0

## cell.folderLabel.text : Optional("dgd")

ASJ DATA : dsdfsdf + 2 + Optional("") + 20.0 + 105.0

## cell.folderLabel.text : Optional("dsdfsdf")

ASJ DATA : sdf + 3 + Optional("") + 20.0 + 105.0

## cell.folderLabel.text : Optional("sdf")

ASJ DATA : sdff + 4 + Optional("") + 20.0 + 105.0
cell.folderLabel.text : Optional("sdff")

is there any idea of this situation or some problems in my source?
It makes me crazy, so I need some help... T_T
Thank you.

Comment: can be layout issue?, use view hierarchy debuger

Comment: read some tutorials, i hope this code will not get to release. Don't set UI size in cellForItemAt. Use your FolderCollectionViewCell or storyboard

Comment: Is there any solutions to set the size of the cells in the storyboard in many devices when device size is all different? I wanted to search, but I couldn't find..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere you're setting the frame origin for folderLabel (I can only see a size being set). They key thing is when you set the size, you only set it (to zero) when the text is empty. As the cell is being reused, you'll need to set the size all the time, so it will no longer be zero.

```
if(nameList[indexPath.row] == "")
{
    cell.folderLabel.text = ""
    cell.folderLabel.frame.size = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    cell.folderImage.frame.size = CGSize(width: cellSize, height: cellSize + 20)
}
else  // Add this
{
    cell.folderLabel.frame.size = ...
}
```

Secondly, the last line of this block looks wrong:

```
 cell.folderLabel.frame.size.width = cellSize
 cell.folderLabel.frame.size.height = 20
 cell.folderImage.frame.size.width = cellSize
 cell.folderImage.frame.size.width = cellSize // should be size.height
```